# How to conditionally run maven-release:rollback in jenkins?

Tags: maven, hudson, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I am using **jenkins/hudson** to make maven releases, and sometimes when the builds fails, I have no other way that manual to rollback and then start the jenkins build again. I was wondering if there is any good and configurable way of running **mvn release:rollback** in the end of the build dependent the result of **mvn release:prepare**? I mean, if the release process fails, I want to run maven release:rollback, otherwise not.

Thanks your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your Jenkins job to do a fresh checkout of the source code every time the job is started. So if your release fails before the creation of the release tag, you can fix the problems and just start the release again.

Comment: Part of the release:rollback goal is that it rolls back the SCM updates. It would be nice to have jenkins handle all this, instead of manually having to revert a commit.

Comment: @kenny Well, `release:rollback` reverts the SCM updates on the POMs but it does not remove the created release tag (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-229). So there are still manual steps involved.